# How I can put one space before and after list elements?

Tags: python, list

How I can put one space before and after list elements?

For example `list=['A','B','C']`

I want

`list=[' A ',' B ',' C ']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [f-strings or formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) and [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
lst = [f' {x} ' for x in lst]
```

Comment: Could you please also tell me if I want to remove `\n` from some elements of list, what I should do?

Comment: for example 'hello\n' should be `hello`

Comment: @elham [x.strip for x in lst]

Comment: thank you. some of them are like this `hello\nhow are you`. I mean `\n` is attached to another word.

Comment: `import re; lst = [re.sub(r'\n', '', x) for x in lst]`

Answer (score 1):

```
#Simple way
list = [' '+x+' ' for x in list] 

#F-strings way
lits = [f' {x} ' for x in list]
```

Answer (score -1):

Didnt you just answer the question yourself

by using:

```
list = [' A ',' B ',' C ']
```

The code already works
when you print

```
print(list[0])
```

it will print 'A' with a space before and after it

In order to verify this see the difference by printing the first charectors of the first list and second list

first list = list = ['A', 'B', 'C']
second list = list = [' A ', ' B ', ' C ']

Comment: here OP has asked to how to save that data in that format not how to see the print. also there is difference in both of them when they print as `' A '!='A'` there is two character difference

Comment: @sahasrara62 oh sorry i didn't understand what he meant